# UnknownFormatConversionException is caused by symbol '%' in String.format()

Tags: java, string, replace, string-formatting

```
String template = "%s and '%'";
String result = String.format(template, "my string");
System.out.println(result);
```

**Expected**:

```
my string and '%'
```

**But result is**:

```
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '''
```

**Why?** How to correctly declared the sequence `'%'` so that it's ignored by `String.format()`?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`%` is already used by format specifiers so it requires an additional `%` to display that character:

```
String template = "%s and '%%'";
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Reimeus. This issue was killing me after trying hell number of possible solutions on the stackoverflow.